# How to get the Selected Check box text as well as text view text from a listview when a on click of a button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I tried several solution which are found in stackoverflow and other blogs but still i could not make it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Object Oriented Programmdsf dsf fs sdf sdf sfd sdf ing"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:padding="15dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Certificate Level"
        android:textSize="14sp"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/vwID"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/vwSubjectIndex"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        />
      </LinearLayout>
```

In My Activity.onCreate method i set some data to listview with checkbox(in above format)
Below layout is activity layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.greencode.ndl.notebook.SubjectsActivity"

    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select an item/s"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="208dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.83" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/continue_subject_selection"
        android:id="@+id/btnGo"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        />
      </LinearLayout>
```

I need to get the vwID text and the checkbox text? How can i do this

Comment: Something like String id = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.vwId)).text. and the same-ish for the checkBox. Syntax might not be correct, it's been a while since I programmed in android.

Comment: It's not working, because there are bunch of check box in the listview

Comment: What if you give them each a unique id?

Comment: Are you using an adapter here?

Comment: yes, i am using an adapter which is extended FirebaseListAdapter